# Mysql - Aggregate function is very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a mysql database with very large tables. I often run queries that involve aggregate functions. Queries with the aggregate functions like MIN, MAX, SUM, COUNT are running very slow. Please help me to increase the speed.

```
SELECT MIN(PeriodTime) FROM ResultsTable WHERE (OrderId=271)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ResultsTable WHERE (OrderId=271);  ==> returns 258021
```

Total rows in that table = 1213284, My Query matches = 258021 rows.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an index on `ResultsTable` that covers `PeriodTime` and `OrderId`. That will help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the info. How do i do the similar thing on the VIEWS.

Comment: MySQL does not support indexing on views. However the views will utilize the index when they are executed.

Comment: Do you know of any other alternatives when I want to run similar queries on views? Thanks.

Comment: Not using views. Really if the query runs fast the view should also. I tend to not use too many views, and I prefer using stored procedures for most of my work. However views have there place, but proper indexing will work there as well.